# Should you use the [megaupload] tag for the MEGA API?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854387/mega-api-dowload-a-file) is what curiousity stems from.

So in the post they ask a question regarding an API library used to access the services of https://mega.nz. The reason this is strange is because MEGA Ltd. was founded by Kim Dotcom right after megaupload was shut down. MEGA offers nearly the exact same service as megaupload did and was founded by the same person so does this warrant the question being tagged with megaupload?

My initial reaction is no, but I would assume that the services share a similar if not almost identical code base. This just seems like a very eccentric (as is Kim Dotcom himself) case that I thought could do with some addressing. If not for a "by the books" ruling then for your input on how independent 2 services are that are made by the same person, provide the same thing, were created back-to-back and even share a name.

If you'd like more info on these two:

[Megaupload (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megaupload)

[Mega (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_(service))

I should also note that there is no comparable tag for the MEGA API and maybe OP was just trying to further classify his fairly generic question in terms of content.

Comment: I would say that it should probably have its own [tag:mega-api] tag

Comment: Oh, look, an inappropriate tag that's attracting off topic questions and is only on a handful of questions.  Would be a shame if something happened to it.

Comment: Well, there are some legit questions. Considering the service is defunct, maybe those questions should be closed as no longer reproducible?  I've added the mega-api tag and applied it to questions where it was relevant.  Folks should visit the flag and help VTC stuff that is crap.

Comment: @Will visit the flag? Where is this flag you speak of?

Comment: @TinyGiant you... you didn't.  That tag had *children*, you animal!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say no.

AFAIK, Megaupload was just your typical file sharing site. It didn't have any API or anything.

Mega on the other hand is somewhat different, in that files are encrypted client-side, and can only be decrypted client-side is the user has the correct key. More-importantly, it has an API which the old and shutdown Megaupload did not have.

Seeing as how this site is a programming site, I think a tag called `mega-api` for the new Mega API would make sense. We don't really handle general questions about Mega or Megaupload here, and continuing to tag questions with a tag for a shutdown service doesn't really make sense unless you are asking about someting that you can no longer even use for some bizarre reason.

Comment: Pretty much what I thought as well. I found it a bit strange that we have a tag for [megaupload] with a description that just states it no longer exists. Like what's even the point? I've never requested one myself but do you think this is something to make a burninate request for?